# How default exception handler work

Tags: java, exception

When we try to run the following program then we get the error that  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`

```
class excp {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int x = 0;
    int a = 30/x;
  }
}
```

but when we ask somebody how these works, then he tell me that this exception is cautch by the default exception handler, So i could't understand how this defualt exception handler works.
Plz elaborate this.

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_uncaught_handler.shtml

Comment: If you don't try/catch for an exception, then the JVM catches it.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting JLS 11 :

30/x - violates the semantic constraint of Java Language - hence the exception will occur.

```
If no catch clause that can handle an exception can be found, 
then the **current thread** (the thread that encountered the exception) is terminated
```

Before termination - the uncaught exception is handled as per the following rules :

```
(1) If the current thread has an uncaught exception handler set, 
then that handler is executed.

(2) Otherwise, the method uncaughtException is invoked for the ThreadGroup 
that is the parent of the current thread. 
If the ThreadGroup and its parent ThreadGroups do not override uncaughtException, 
then the default handler's **uncaughtException** method is invoked.
```

In your case :

After the exception it goes into Thread class

```
     /**
     * Dispatch an uncaught exception to the handler. This method is
     * intended to be called only by the JVM.
     */
    private void dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
        getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(this, e);
    }
```

Then it goes to the ThreadGroup uncaugthException as per Rule 2 - Since no exceptionHandler is defined it goes to Else if - and the thread is terminated

```
public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.uncaughtException(t, e);
        } else {
            Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler ueh =
                Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
            if (ueh != null) {
                ueh.uncaughtException(t, e);
            } **else if (!(e instanceof ThreadDeath)) {
                System.err.print("Exception in thread \""
                                 + t.getName() + "\" ");
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }**
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever inside a method, if an exception has occurred, the method creates an Object known as **Exception Object** and hands it off to the run-time system(JVM). The exception object contains exception class name, description of the exception, and stack trace (location of the program where the exception has occurred).

The run-time system starts searching from the method in which exception occurred, proceeds through call stack in the reverse order in which methods were called. If it finds  appropriate handler then it passes the occurred exception to it. If run-time system searches all the methods on call stack and couldn’t have found the appropriate handler then run-time system handover the Exception Object to **default exception handler**, which is part of run-time system. This handler prints exception class name, exception description and stacktrace and terminates program abnormally.